# Why I can not assign the value in public location in java

Tags: java, variables, instance

```
public class Test {
    int a=10;
    a=20;
}
```

why I can not assign the value as above;

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: However the answers below are correct, based on your question it looks  like you are missing something more important and basic in the Java language. Please try to explain the context - what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

When you declare an instance variable (class member) like this:

```
public class Test {
    int a=10; 
}
```

it means that *any* instance of class Test will have its own copy of this variable and it will be [instantiated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) to 10.

Java allows an [assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html) upon declaration of instance variables, but after the variable was already declared it can be assigned only in:

- an initializer block
- a constructor
- a method

which is why the second line will fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The value would need to be static or inside of a method to assign the value in this portion of a class. You won't be able to change the value of a in that way unless you declare a static block of code.

try:

```
public class Test {

private static int a = 20;

}
```

or

```
public class Test {

    private int a = 10;

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        a = 20;
}
```

or

```
public class Test {

static {
    int a = 10;
    a = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is called initialization block

```
public class Test {

    int a=10; 
    {a=20;}

}
```

Comment: While technically correct, you should use a constructor here.

Comment: Of course, but that answers the question. In compile time, this line is added to the constructor.

Answer (score -3):

EDITED:

You can alter variables values only in methods. Java is objective language not procedural.

Comment: I didn't saw that there's doubled "a". I thought it's "a" and "b".